# How to enable and edit pepk.jar file Google Play App Signing

Tags: android, google-play-services, sign, android-keystore

I have uploaded app to play store after long time didn't knew about that,after uploading successfully I found out that map is not working  Now I follow thier instuction to do it but find that my app also have some bug so if I upload new version is there any posibilty that I can upload  store key and while following their instuction I cann't Enter a word for my password in cmd[image].

any other way to fix it .
I have read some tuto from stackoverflow but facing some problem  cann't  comment there.
if you cann't answer please ignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I entered the Password and press enter button and it worked
as I was following answer from stackoverflow user

```
java -jar PATH_TO_PEPK --keystore=PATH_TO_KEYSTORE --alias=ALIAS_YOU_USE_TO_SIGN_APK --output=PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE --encryptionkey=GOOGLE_ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

now one file is done.

Answer (score 1):

Just type in your password. It **won't** show on the screen but it recognizes it.

Let me know if it works out successfully.